# Retrieve the encryption state of AWS SNS with PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-sns

I've investigated all AWS SNS PowerShell Cmdlets that would retrieve whether an SNS topic is encrypted or not, but I can see any of the attributes retrieved from

```
Get-SNSTopicAttribute
```

relates to the encryption configuration of the topic. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to check if the response includes `KmsMasterKeyId` property. Since, You must enter a valid CMK ARN.

For instance:

[image]

Note that when the SNS is not encrypted the `KmsMasterKeyId` property is missing.

[image]